# C#/.Net Using ThreadLocal with Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Let's imagine code like this:

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<int> MyInt = new ThreadLocal<int>(() => 3);

DoSomething()
{
    var A = DoSomethingElse()
    MyInt += A;
}
```

So, every thread would have a copy of MyInt.

but if we did something like that:

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<int> MyInt = new ThreadLocal<int>(() => 3);

async DoSomething()
{
    var A = await DoSomethingElse();
    MyInt += A.Result();
}
```

Is is possible that, when the execution resumes from the await call, we would be in another thread and MyInt += A would add A to the wrong MyInt?

Comment: Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @khoroshevj 's answer is incomplete. It isn't that simple.

If, when you `await`, there is synchronization context available it will be captured and you will resume on that context because you have not explicitly told it that it doesn't need to with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Be aware that you may resume on the same context with `ConfigureAwait(false)` because that is not an instruction to switch context, it is an indication that it is OK to resume on a different context if that is what the runtime decides is best.

So, pretty much if this is not a console app and you have not set a new `SynchronizationContext.Current`, then you will resume where you left off.

If `DoSomethingElse()` or anything in it's relative call stack also accesses the threadlocal variable then you will be in trouble.

So for safety you should probably use `AsyncLocal` but the code you have shown should work as intended.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I never had problems with ThreadLocal, but 2 days ago it hit me that await could resume on a different context. So, if I understand you can control that with ConfigureAwait, right?

Comment: You can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to say "I don't care what context I resume on". It doesn't always switch context, but that's OK because you really only care about a specific context when you __need__ to access the UI, or HttpContext or ThreadLocal, etc., in which case you intentionally do not use `ConfigureAwait`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is no guarantee that execution resumes on the same thread. But you can use AsyncLocal instead
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx